# Appstore TestFlight giving Submit for review error

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

It was work fine at start. I have invited 2 people. But suddenly it said that No Builds Available. And then saying my app expired. I deleted app and reloaded it. Now when I click submit for review giving this error message.

"There was an error processing your request. Please try again later."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEqtw.png)

I tried delete and upload again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.